# What is the probability of all values appearing once when picking 2 random card values n times, given the two values are unique?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of all values appearing once when picking 2 random card values *n* times, knowing these 2 values are unique?

Here's an illustration:

Suppose you have a deck of *k* cards, ranging from *1* to *k*, you pick *2* cards out, then record the values, and put them back You repeat this for *n-1* more times. What is the probability that by the end of *n* times looking through the cards, you have seen all card values from *1* to *k*?

The solution I got through *10,000,000* simulations were 42.19% where *n = 10* and *k = 9*. Though this is merely an estimate, and a formula would sort things out better for me.

The formula I use for calculating *1* picked card after *n* trials is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^r$$

Is there anyway to inject this problem into the formula to figure out the probability of *2* picked cards instead of *1*? If not, is there a formula to calculate the probability of it happening for *n* trials and *k* number of cards?

**Edit:** Credits to *@awkward* for the solution to the question.
For good measures: I have compared the solutions of *n = 1...50* & *k = 9* to my simulations and they were almost complete matches.

In addition, this solution also works with *c* number of cards with some minor adjustments:

$$p_0 = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} \left( \frac{\binom{k-j}{c}}{\binom{k}{c}} \right)^n$$

I have tested this through several simulations and it does match. I will update you when the computer finishes these new simulations.

***Edit #2:*** After finishing simulations, I can finally conclude with confidence that the formula works for *2* ≤ *c* ≤ *k* where *c* is the number of cards, *k* is the number of unique elements, and *n* is the number of trials performed.

For programming nerds: If you plan to use these formulas, here's my shot of it:

````
private static double calculateSum(int head, int tail, int time){
        // n: unique elements - tail
        // k: picks - head
        double sum = 0;
        if (time == 1){
            for (int k = 0; k <= tail; k++){
                sum += (Math.pow(-1, k) * nCr(tail, k) * Math.pow((1 - (double) k / tail), head));
            }
        } else if (time > 1){
            sum = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= tail; j++){
                sum += (Math.pow(-1, j) * nCr(tail, j) * Math.pow(( nCr(tail-j, time)/(double)nCr(tail,time)), head));
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static long factorial(int n){
        long toReturn = 1;
        if (n <= 1) return toReturn;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) toReturn *= i;
        return toReturn;
    }

    private static long nCr(int n, int r){
        return factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n-r));
    }
```
````

Comment: My first instinct would be to use the computer in a different manner than you have.  Limiting the values of $n$ and $k$ to various values $\leq 10$, you have that there are $\displaystyle ~\binom{k}{2}^n$ possible distributions of the $n$ pairs selected.  I would have the computer cycle through these distributions, and report back the exact fraction of the time that all of the numbers $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ show up at least once.  Then, I would look for a pattern in the data, try to use this pattern to form a hypothesis, and then try to prove the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with pairs selected can be solved via the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

Let's say a set of $n$ pairs has "property $i$" if card $i$ is not found in the set, for $1 \le i \le k$.  Define $S_j$ to be the total probability of all the draws with $j$ of the properties, for $1 \le j \le k$. Then
$$S_j = \binom{k}{j} \left( \frac{\binom{k-j}{2}}{\binom{k}{2}} \right)^n$$
By inclusion/exclusion, the probability of a set of draws with none of the properties, i.e. in which each card is seen at least once, is
$$p_0 = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^j S_j$$
In the case of $n=10$, $k=9$ we compute $p_0 = 0.422213$, which is consistent with the results of the simulation cited.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we do not really care about which cards we draw, so it is viable to just consider the total number of seen cards. Before the first draw this is $0$, after the first draw it is $2$. Generally it can range between $0$ and $k$.

If at some step this number is $l$ it is easy to see that the result of the next step only depends on this $l$, so this forms a Markov chain.

So suppose we have already seen $l$ cards, how high is the probabilty to draw $0,1,2$ unknown cards? There are $k-l$ unknown cards, so the first card is with probability $l/k$ known and with $1-l/k$ unknown.

In the first case the second draw is with probability $(l-1)/(k-1)$ known and $(k-l)/(k-1) = 1-(l-1)/(k-1)$ unknown.

In the second case the second draw is with prob $l/(k-1)$ known and with $1-l/(k-1)$ unknown.

So we get in total:

- $(l/k)((l-1)/(k-1)) = (l(l-1))/(k(k-1))$ for both draws are known
- $(l/k)((k-l)/(k-1)) = (l(k-l))/(k(k-1))$ for first known, second unknown
- $((k-l)/k)(l/(k-1)) = (l(k-l))/(k(k-1))$ for first unknown, second known
- $((k-l)/k)((k-l-1)/(k-1)) = ((k-l)(k-l-1))/(k(k-1))$ both unknown

So given we now know $l$ cards we have a probability for $l$ in the next step of

- $(l(l-1))/(k(k-1))$ for $l$
- $2(l(k-l))/(k(k-1))$ for $l+1$
- $((k-l)(k-l-1))/(k(k-1))$ for $l+2$

This then gives us an upper band $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ matrix $M$ so that the distribution of $l$ after $n$ steps is given by $M^n\cdot(1,0\ldots,0)$.

This Matrix is defined by mapping $e_l$ to $A_le_l+B_le_{l+1}+C_le_{l+2}$.
Thus a vector $\sum x_le_l$ is mapped to $\sum (x_lA_l + x_{l-1}B_{l-1} + x_{l-2}C_{l-2})e_l$.

Thus an eigenvector has to satisfy
$$ \lambda x_l = x_lA_l + x_{l-1}B_{l-1} + x_{l-2}C_{l-2} $$
or
$$ x_l(\lambda-A_l) = x_{l-1}B_{l-1} + x_{l-2}C_{l-2} $$
with
$$ x_0(\lambda-A_0) = 0$$
and
$$ x_1(\lambda-A_1) = x_0A_0 $$
This implies that either $\lambda=A_0$ or $x_0=0$. In the first case $x$ is fully defined by $x_0$. In second case we can apply this argument to $x_1$.
This finally gives us that the eigenvalues are exactly
$A_0,\ldots,A_k$ with the eigenvector to $A_l$ being given by:

- For $m<l$ $x_m=0$
- $x_l\neq 0$ arbitrary
- All other $x_m$ given recursively from $x_l$

(hereby we get if $x_l=1$ then $x_{l+1} = \frac{B_{l+1}}{A_{l}-A_{l+1}}$, $x_{l+2} = \frac{B_{l+2}x_{l+1} + C_{l+2}}{A_l-A_{l+2}} = \frac{B_{l+2}B_{l+1}}{(A_l-A_{l+1})(A_l-A_{l+2})} + \frac{C_{l+2}}{A_l-A_{l+2}}$ and so on).

Note that only $A_0,A_1=0$.

Thus the matrix $M$ is diagonalizable if we scrap the first two rows/columns (which we no not need, as the first goes to 2 and the second does not happen). Thus if we know $k$ we can calculate $M = PDP^{-1}$ and thus $M^n = PD^nP^{-1}$, which we can then calculate symbolically.

(nota bene that scrapping the first two rows/cols will mean starting on the first turn).

If we do not know $k$ we can do this symbolically, but it is not pretty:

If $b_l$ is the $l$-th eigenvector then $P = (b_l/\|b_l\|)_{l=0,\ldots k}$, $P^{-1}=P^T$, $D=diag(A_0,\ldots,A_k)$.

So this then gives us a symbolic form, but not a pretty one.

For $k=9$:

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
\frac{1}{36} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{7}{18} & \frac{1}{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{7}{12} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{5}{12} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{5}{18} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{5}{18} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{5}{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{7}{12} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{7}{18} & \frac{7}{9} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{2}{9} & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

also
$$ D=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{7}{9} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{7}{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{18} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{12} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{36}
\end{array}\right)$$
and up to normalisation
$$ P=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -6 & 21 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -5 & 15 & -35 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 10 & -20 & 35 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -3 & 6 & -10 & 15 & -21 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 3 & -4 & 5 & -6 & 7 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right)$$

Then
$$ PD^n P^{-1} =
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
\frac{1}{36^{n}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-\frac{7}{36^{n}} + \frac{7}{12^{n}} & \frac{1}{12^{n}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{21}{36^{n}} - \frac{42}{12^{n}} + \frac{21}{6^{n}} & -\frac{6}{12^{n}} + \frac{6}{6^{n}} & \frac{1}{6^{n}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{35}{36^{n}} + \frac{105}{12^{n}} - \frac{105}{6^{n}} & \frac{15 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{15}{12^{n}} - \frac{30}{6^{n}} & \frac{5 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{5}{6^{n}} & \frac{5^{n}}{18^{n}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-\frac{140 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{35}{36^{n}} - \frac{140}{12^{n}} + \frac{210}{6^{n}} & -\frac{60 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{20 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{20}{12^{n}} + \frac{60}{6^{n}} & -\frac{20 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{10 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{10}{6^{n}} & -\frac{4 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{4 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} & \frac{5^{n}}{12^{n}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{21 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{210 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{105 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{21}{36^{n}} + \frac{105}{12^{n}} - \frac{210}{6^{n}} & \frac{15 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{90 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{60 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{15}{12^{n}} - \frac{60}{6^{n}} & \frac{10 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{30 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{30 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{10}{6^{n}} & \frac{6 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{6 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{12 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} & \frac{3 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{3 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} & \frac{7^{n}}{12^{n}} & 0 & 0 \\
-\frac{42 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{7 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} - \frac{140 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{105 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{7}{36^{n}} - \frac{42}{12^{n}} + \frac{105}{6^{n}} & -\frac{30 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{6 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} - \frac{60 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{60 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{6}{12^{n}} + \frac{30}{6^{n}} & -\frac{20 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{5 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} - \frac{20 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{30 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{5}{6^{n}} & -\frac{12 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{4 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} - \frac{4 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{12 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} & -\frac{6 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{3 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} + \frac{3 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} & -\frac{2 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{2 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} & \frac{7^{n}}{9^{n}} & 0 \\
\frac{21 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{7 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} + \frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{1}{36^{n}} + \frac{7}{12^{n}} - \frac{21}{6^{n}} + 1 & \frac{15 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{6 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} + \frac{15 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{20 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{1}{12^{n}} - \frac{6}{6^{n}} + 1 & \frac{10 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{5 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} + \frac{5 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{10 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{1}{6^{n}} + 1 & \frac{6 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{4 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} + \frac{5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{4 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + 1 & \frac{3 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{3 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} - \frac{5^{n}}{12^{n}} + 1 & \frac{7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{2 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} + 1 & -\frac{7^{n}}{9^{n}} + 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

and multiplying this with the starting distribution $(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ after the first turn (two cards known) we get
$$ P_{n+1} = \left(\frac{1}{36^{n}},\,-\frac{7}{36^{n}} + \frac{7}{12^{n}},\,\frac{21}{36^{n}} - \frac{42}{12^{n}} + \frac{21}{6^{n}},\,\frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{35}{36^{n}} + \frac{105}{12^{n}} - \frac{105}{6^{n}},\,-\frac{140 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{35}{36^{n}} - \frac{140}{12^{n}} + \frac{210}{6^{n}},\,\frac{21 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{210 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{105 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{21}{36^{n}} + \frac{105}{12^{n}} - \frac{210}{6^{n}},\,-\frac{42 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{7 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} - \frac{140 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} + \frac{105 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} + \frac{7}{36^{n}} - \frac{42}{12^{n}} + \frac{105}{6^{n}},\,\frac{21 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{7 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} + \frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{1}{36^{n}} + \frac{7}{12^{n}} - \frac{21}{6^{n}} + 1\right)$$

This means that after $n+1$ turns we get a probability of
$$ \frac{21 \cdot 7^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{7 \cdot 7^{n}}{9^{n}} + \frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{18^{n}} - \frac{35 \cdot 5^{n}}{12^{n}} - \frac{1}{36^{n}} + \frac{7}{12^{n}} - \frac{21}{6^{n}} + 1 $$
for having seen all cards.

For $n=9$ this gives us a prob of $24814766725/58773123072$ or $0.422212831783682$.